# Link current frame between scenes

Tags: python, animation, scripting, video-sequence-editor, scene

I am new to blender scripting. so, If I have two scenes open, one being the master scene with VSE only, and other scene with animation. Is there a way to link their play-heads so that if I move current frame on VSE, it moves on animation scene as well ?

This important for in-context changes during animation, when multiple scenes are composited. I have been trying to replicate functionality of After Effects in Blender.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current` to read and write this value via a Python console or a little script.

Comment: Can you describe what kinds of changes you're wanting to pick up? I'm not understanding how this would be useful.

Comment: @Samoth thank you for that. I realized I could access that data through that code. But I don't how to right an expression which would do this. Could you give me a step by step instruction. I am very new with no scripting background.

Comment: @Matt yes I will try to describe a situation. Imagine you built two related scenes which are part of a  motion graphics package. In a new  third scene with just a VSE with the two previous scenes added, you would edit them on top of each other as layers, and perfect the animation's timing. So you open scene 3 (VSE) with say scene 2 (animation) side by side. You see the output of scene3,which is main output, and make timing changes is scene2. This allows to to see the whole thing in context.

Comment: But the issue I have is that if change play head on scene3 it doesn't sync with scene2. This is crucial in order to make changes. In after effects if you have a nested comp layered in another comp, if u stop at a frame, u go into the nested comp, u r still at that frame. So making tiny changes is very easy. Hope I'm making it clear. Its a little long winded.

Comment: Why would you use scripting when you could use scene strips in the VSE and proxy the OpenGL viewport on your animation scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was given the solution by @batFINGER, in another post.

[add driver to Scene.current_frame?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53977/add-driver-to-scene-current-frame)

by using app handlers.