# add driver to Scene.current_frame?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

Is it possible to add driver to `Scene.current_frame` so that one scene's current frame can drive other scene's?

If not is there a way to link them continuously?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just the same question as the one you asked yesterday?

Comment: @RayMairlot hmmm yeah saw comment after posted answer.  Will leave on this one for now.

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes, sorry about that. I didn't know about drivers then, so thought this was a more direct question. Will link that to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a driver to the frame_current property of the scene object, error message from console.

```
>>> C.scene.driver_add('frame_current')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "frame_current" not animatable
```

You could do something with [frame change handlers](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.app.handlers.html).

```
import bpy

def lockscenes(scene):
    if scene.name == "Scene": # master scene
        f = scene.frame_current
        for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
            if scene.name == "Scene":
                continue
            scene.frame_set(f)
    return None

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(lockscenes)
```